# How can I redistribute .Net Framework3.5 SP1 with my application by ClickOnce on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'm sorry I'm english a little.

I want to redistribute .Net Framework3.5 SP1 using clickonce application(publish tab)

I check .Net Framework3.5 SP1 , but it can not find `DotNetFx35Sp1Setup.exe` when build process.

If i check .Net Framework4 , it works well(VS2010).

so i tried in vs2008, it works well.

How can i include .netfx35sp1 into clickonce application on vs2010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you publishing the application from??? via visual studio 2010?? in that case.. go to your project startup file->properties->publish.. go to pre-requisites. where you will see options like download from vendor, download from the same location, download from the server location. You choose download from vendor's website and also you will see the list of prerequisite available in that popup, where you can check the prerequisites you need. you check the checkbox for .net3.5sp1 and publish.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I choose download from the server location. but we can't access internet. so I had downloaded .Netfx3.5sp1 for redistribution but it doesn't work. (vs2010) . anyway fx4 is works well.